# Git Extensions shows results that don't match search filters as well as results that match

Tags: git, search, grep, versioning

Git extensions when searching using different filters (for example, commit message) will show results with commit messages that don't contain my search string. This is really annoying is there any way to prevent this?

Command line git filtering using --grep shows only the appropriate commits.

Comment: Mind showing an example of what you are executing?

Comment: the example is start git extensions, go to the "Filter:" field and type in some string that you are searching for eg "abc" and hit enter.  By default it searches in commit messages.  When the results show up it shows matching commits but also a lot of commits that don't even contain "abc" in the message at all.

Answer (score 3):

That quick filter seems to show commits with containing the string and the trees that depend upon those commits.  Going to the [git extensions documentation](https://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/browse_repository.html?highlight=filter), it seems to do what you want, you have to use the "advanced filter".  This is in the context menu that can be reached by right clicking the pane that shows the commit log. See below:

[image: how to get to the advanced filter]

Comment: Thank you very much.  This got me really close to the desired output i thought it actually fully worked until i found 2 commits (so far) lower down the tree that don't match the message i specified.  I'm not sure if i'm missing something but i went to advanced filters, checked message and typed in the message i wanted to look for.

Comment: I don't know if it can be convinced to look for word boundaries.  I was playing with it with one of my own repositories and searched for a particular word, and one resulting line didn't seem to match, until I realized the word was embedded in another word in the commit message.

Comment: Yeah I thought of that but that's not the case here.  I'm getting merge commits and normal commits that don't contain the message i'm searching for.  Could there be some other options I might have enabled in Git Extensions?  I tried looking for an option like "show adjacent commits" but I couldn't find one that would do something like this that is obvious.  I will up vote your answer because it's closer to the desired output but for some reason it's not quite there.  It feels like i'm missing something simple, like a checkmark somewere.